# C# WinForms: Drawing with one or more additional threads. How?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, system.drawing

In case I have a big drawing with all kinds of geometric forms (lines, rectangles, circles, e.t.c.) it takes a lot of time for the thread to draw everything. But in real life, one building is built by more than one workers. So if the drawing is the building and the threads are the builders, it will get drawn a lot faster. But I want to know how.

Can you tell me how? Is it even possible (though I have already asked and the answer was "Yes")? Is it worth it to be used? What are the risks?

If there are questions that I have missed, please tell me about them and answer them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using GDI+ and the `System.Drawing.Graphics` object to render your graphics (rectangles, circles, etc.) to a background drawing surface (e.g. `System.Drawing.Bitmap` Object): Instance members of the `System.Drawing.Graphics` object that you would need to use are **not thread safe**. [See MSDN documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Given this, I would not use more than one "builder" thread to render your graphics.

Instead, my recommendation would be to do all of your drawing to a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` object in a **single** background thread rather than multiple background threads if possible.  You can use a status bar or other indicator to let the user know that your program is working in the background.

Comment: Yes - I have certainly done drawing to a bitmap in a secondary thread, posted the bitmap to the UI thread and rendered it there, (not in C#). Works fine.  Not tried it with multiple bitmaps/graphics objects and it seems reasonable that anything that performed its function using specialist, dedicated hardware, (eg. a graphics chip subsystem), would be thred-unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

WinForms objects have strong thread affinity, making it impossible to manipulate a form or control from a thread different than the one who created it.

That said, it's worth investigating if this assertion is true for `Graphics` as well.

From the [System.Drawing.Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) class docs:

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are
>   thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.

Doesn't smell good: All drawing methods are instance members. You can't spread operations on the `Graphics` object accross several threads.

Answer (score -1):

As a simple example you can use threads to do multiple tasks using the ThreadStart delegate method, it would look something along these lines:

```
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MethodToExecuteOnSecondThread));
        t.Start();
        while (!t.IsAlive)
        {
            //do something to show we're working perhaps?
            UpdateMyGuiWithALoadingBar(); 
        }
```

You're second thread then goes off and executes the ThreadStart() delegate method while you main thread stays responsive.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the issue of thread safety/affinity in Winforms and System.Drawing

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question asked if there is a option he can use with more than one 'builder'/'thread' my answer was intended to demonstrate a basic use of more than one 'builder' as he put it

Comment: no offense intended but it looks like the question is kind of "is it possible to make a baby in 1 month" and you answer "hire 9 women". (Well, kind of. Obviously I exagerate both the question and your answer to illustrate my thought).

Comment: No offense taken, the answer was specifically directed at answering this part of the question "So if the drawing is the building and the threads are the builders, it will get drawn a lot faster. But I want to know how." I assumed this meant, I want to know how to create more than one builder.