# Drawing into a shared graphics buffer out of different threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, graphics, buffer

I'm trying to write a class with drawing operation that directy draw onto the screen. My Idea was to have a constant loop, which is rendering the graphics buffer and several functions, that write into the graphics buffer (lines, rectangles, etc). Now there is the problem with the threads. I can't write into the graphics buffer, when it is used in a loop in a different thread. But I need the different thread to keep a constant performance/framerate. I tried to kind of create a "shared" buffer in form of a bitmap, but the performance just sucks. Has anyone got any idead, how to solve this? The current error message is: System.InvalidOperationException @ myGraphics.Clear(Color.Black);

```
class drawingOnScreen
{
    IntPtr desktop; //a pointer to the desktop
    Graphics g; //the graphics object

    BufferedGraphicsContext currentContext; 
    BufferedGraphics myBuffer; //graphics buffer

    Thread renderThread; //the thread

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);

    public void drawLine(Vector2D point1, Vector2D point2, float width, Color color) //Vector2D is basically like Point2D
    {
        myBuffer.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(color, width), point1.x, point1.y, point2.x, point2.y); //trying to draw a line into the buffer
    }

    public void init() //initializing everything
    {
        desktop = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero); //setting up for drawing directly to the screen
        g = Graphics.FromHdc(desktop); //setting up for drawing directly to the screen

        currentContext = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current; //setting up the render buffer
        myBuffer = currentContext.Allocate(g, new Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 300)); //setting up the render buffer

        renderThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(renderOp)); //setting up a seperated thread for rendering to avoid lag etc.
        renderThread.Start(); //starting the thread
    }

    void renderOp() //the render thread as a loop
    {
        while (true)
        {
            myBuffer.Graphics.Clear(Color.Black); //clear the background

            myBuffer.Render(); //render when every drawing operation is finished
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any tries awnsering my question.

Comment: You could try moving the Allocate() call to just above the while loop in renderOp()?  I've never actually used BufferedGraphics, so take that with a grain of salt...

Comment: Your `renderOp` method doesn't make much sense. Are you assuming that some other thread will draw on the `Graphics` surface between the time you call `Clear` and the time you call `Render`? In any case, the likely problem is that you are accessing the `Graphics` instance from a thread other than the one on which it was created. What is the *complete* error message that is displayed along with that exception?

Comment: The `Graphics` class is not thread safe. See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570585/c-sharp-winforms-drawing-with-one-or-more-additional-threads-how.